# WP7 - why does click adcontrol then back button cause page backkeypress event fired on form re-entry?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a number of Windows Phone 7 apps, which have a main page with a custom BackKeyPress event that on the main form throws a custom exception, in order to pass testing and get to the marketplace.

These forms have an AdControl on them.  For some reason, when you click on an Ad, either in testing or production, then hit the back button, the BackKeyPress event is fired on the main form.

I have code in place to handle the issue, but does anyone know why it is giving this behavior?  I can understand the event firing when the back button is pressed while on the form, but why is it fired to re-enter the form?

Is this a known bug?

I have implemented code to solve this issue, but if a bug, will my workaround code for an apparent Microsoft issue either be moot or potentially harmful in the future if the bug is fixed?

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing that comes to my mind here is that the main page is not releasing properly when navigating away from it.
I haven't used the MS AdControl in a few months because it is not useful for non-US developers but when I was trying it out I remember that it would hold pages in memory if you did not unregister all the event bindings
So look at shutting it down in OnNavigatingFrom and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this problem.  When debugging, it looks like the OnNavigatedFrom event is never fired, so there's no tombstoning that's happening and I don't see any place in code where I can unwire that event.

I figured it out.
You have to wire up events in the Adcontrol.AdEngaged to remove the back or AdDisengaged events to readd the back event handler.